# Getting functions from websites

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

In a website how can I get the returned output from functions in chrome console. For example if the website was `http://www.example.com` if I entered `abc()` in chrome console, it would return an array of objects.

How would I go about getting this array of objects from the `abc()` function using Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to understand what the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) is, as briefly explained here:

> In JavaScript, there's always a global object defined. In a web browser, when scripts create global variables, they're created as members of the global object (In Node.js this is not the case). The global object's interface **depends on the execution context** in which the script is running.

An example to illustrate this point would be:

**Node**

```
const abc = () => [{ name: 'obj1'}, { name: 'obj2'}]; 
console.log(abc());        // returned array of objects.
console.log(global.abc()); // returned array of objects.
```

**Browser**

```
const abc = () => [{ name: 'obj1'}, { name: 'obj2'}]; 
console.log(abc());        // returned array of objects.
console.log(window.abc()); // returned array of objects.
```

As highlighted, in [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), this depends on the execution context in which the script is running, and thus relies on the use of [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports) to import modules from another file, as a posed to relying on the implicit nature of the global [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) in a web browser environment.